# Why is it better to use wp_enqueue_style than the link tag in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am pretty new to WordPress development. I read that it's better to use `wp_enqueue_style` and `do_action` inside the `functions.php` file rather than linking CSS files directly as I would when not using WordPress.

Why this is a best practice? What are its advantages?

Answer (score 1):

If you have activated child theme then use `get_template_directory_uri()` functions.

If you have activated parent theme then use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` functions.

---

[**get_template_directory_uri**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) will always refer to the parent theme folder for assets.

[**get_stylesheet_directory_uri**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) will refer to the "current" theme folder for assets (which could be the parent or the child, depending on where it is called).

> **Child theme example:**

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my_child_styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
```

> **Parent theme Example**

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my_parent_styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
```

---

**Method-1**

```
// load css into the website's front-end
function mytheme_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css' ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_style' );
```

**Method-2**

```
// Add this code in your functions.php
function add_stylesheet_to_head() {
      echo "<link href='".get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>";
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_stylesheet_to_head' );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but my question was why to use wp_enqueue_style and add_action while you can add link tags at header and link the css files. why the first way is better ?

Comment: @KareemAbdelwahed If another plugin uses the same CSS file, it wouldn't be able to check if the CSS file has already been included in the page. Then the plugin loads the same file for a second time, resulting in duplicate code.
---

Luckily, WordPress has a pretty easy solution to problems like this: registering and enqueueing stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

Because wp-enqueue-style adds scripts/styles to the queue.

Registers the style if source provided (does NOT overwrite) and enqueues.